# how can i download crash logs (datetime, userid, crashid) for last 3 months from crashalytics?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

Currently we log crash reports into crashlytics. Our product activation is dependent on how smoothly first 2 week goes with the product. I am trying to track any specific bugs our user are facing and their frequency for users in their first few weeks. Also if there are any bugs which leads to churn of our active users from our B2B app. Currently our support ticket systems are broken, hence I have to rely on this source of data.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to bulk export crash reports from Fabric, [according to their docs](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/export-crash-report.html):

> Crash reports can be downloaded for any individual session by pressing
>   the “View all sessions” and clicking the “Download .txt” button.
>
> Crash reports are currently not available for consumption via an API.

---

However, there is a way around this. It's not easy, but it'll get you there:

1. [Migrate your project to Firebase](https://fabric.io/blog/the-future-of-fabric/) (which you'll have to do soon anyway).
2. [Connect your Firebase project to Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery).
3. Your Crash data is now available in a SQL-style database.

From there, you can fine tune a SQL query ([full table schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9036484)) to pull out whatever data you want. [There are examples available](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery#working_with_firebase_crashlytics_data_in_bigquery), such as #2 which sounds very similar to your requirements:

> To properly prioritize production plans, a project manager at
>   PineapplePlusPlus ponders how to point out the most pervasive crashes
>   in their product. They produce a query that provides the pertinent
>   points of data:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT issue_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) AS number_of_crashes,
  COUNT(DISTINCT installation_uuid) AS number_of_impacted_user,
  blame_frame.file,
  blame_frame.line
FROM
  `projectId.crashlytics.package_name_ANDROID`
WHERE
  event_timestamp >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL 168 HOUR)
  AND event_timestamp < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY
  issue_id,
  blame_frame.file,
  blame_frame.line
ORDER BY
  number_of_crashes DESC
LIMIT
  10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export Crashlytics Data to BigQuery. 
And you can do Sql in BigQuery. It's very easy to use. Free limit to 10G data.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export